# calculate percentage in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to calculate the width percentage based on children in a div, but for some reason, it doesn't work as expected.

```js
$.each($("div.row"), function(index) {
  let c = $(this).find("div.col").length;

  if (c <= 12) {
    let p = parseInt(c) / parseInt(12) * 100;

    console.log({
      count: c,
      perc: p,
      one: c / 12
    });

    $(this).find("div.col").css("width", p.toString() + "%");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->

<div class="row">
  <div class="col">COL 1</div>
  <div class="col">COL 2</div>
  <div class="col">COL 3</div>
  
</div>
```

but I get some unexpected results. if the .row contains 3 .col elements I expect to get about 33%, so the elements fill the parent element, but it returns 25.

I thought this should be fairly easy.. am I doing something wrong or is there another way of doing this?

Comment: Can you please paste your full code here.

Comment: I've added the html to the original question

Comment: 3/12 = 25%.  If you want equal width columns that split 100% then just do `100/columnCount`.

Comment: `parseInt(c, 10)`. And, you don't need `parseInt(12)`. Just put 12.

Comment: What is `12` doing in `parseInt(c) / parseInt(12) * 100;`

Comment: 12 is the maximum allowed .col elements, so the math should handle any number from 1 to 12

Comment: ok so I think I rather use flex to evenly distribute the elements

Comment: yes! 100/parseInt(c) worked! thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just change the line `let p = parseInt(c) / parseInt(12) * 100;` to `p = 100/parseInt(c)` for equal width

```js
$.each($("div.row"), function (index) {
    let c = $(this).find("div.col").length;

    if (c <= 12) {
         let p = 100/parseInt(c);

        console.log({ count: c, perc: parseInt(p), one: c / 12 });

        $(this).find("div.col").css("width", p.toString() + "%");
    }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">COL 1</div>
    <div class="col">COL 2</div>
    <div class="col">COL 3</div>
    
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```